# Transformation of an integral into series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I am interested in representing the improper integral of a function $f(x)$ as a series the following way:

$$p_k=\frac{\int_k^{k+1} x f(x) \, ds}{\int_k^{k+1} f(x) \, dx}$$

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)=\int_0^{p(0)} f(x) \, dx+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \int_{p(k-1)}^{p(k)} f(x) \, dx$$

In case the sum does not converge, a regularization technique (Ramanujan, Zeta, Dirichlet) should be used.

What would be the values of such integrals for functions $1/(x+1)$, $x$, $x^2$?

Comment: How do you motivate this formula ? I actually find it very interesting

Comment: @Renato Faraone integral on each range is replaced with a weighted dot in its center of mass, then sum over the weights.